# How to use data property with hierarchical data in d3

Tags: d3.js

I have a dataset that is essentially a tree but I think I shouldn't be using the hierarchy layout because what I want to draw does not resemble a tree?

I'm trying to update my diagram using the .data function but am having trouble trying to use it with hierarchical data. So my problem is this:

I have data that resembles this initially:

```
var data = [{
    "name" : "A",
    "hasChildren" : true,
    "children" : [
        {
            "name" : "B",
            "hasChildren" : false
        },
        {
            "name" : "C",
            "hasChildren" : true
         }
     ]
}];
```

I don't even know how to start to use the .data to do this type of update so I don't have a working prototype so I'm going to try my best to describe:

So to represent A I have a square that is 200 x 200 because it has two children. The square is clickable because one of A's children, C, has children. When I click on the square I get new data:

```
var data = [{
    "name" : "A",
    "hasChildren" : true,
    "children" : [
        {
            "name" : "B",
            "hasChildren" : false
        },
        {
            "name" : "C",
            "hasChildren" : true,
            "children" : [
                {
                    "name" : "D",
                    "hasChildren" : false
                }
             ]
         }
     ]
}];
```

and a new square is drawn to represent C's children which is 100x100 since it only has one child and uses D to draw that square. 
(I know I can put the number of children in as a piece of data, but what I'm trying to do is use the new information to draw)

Hope my explanation is clear enough :p.

This is just a basic idea of what I want to do. Could someone explain to me how I can use .data to check for updates in the nested form and then update the diagram based on that?

Thanks!

Comment: What you're describing sounds like a [treemap](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582). Is that what you want?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not what I want. I'm just wondering if it's possible to use .data and update to draw something related to the new data coming in, D.

Comment: Yes -- that's the entire point of `.data()`. Did you have a look at the tutorials and examples on the D3 website? While I don't think that there's anything exactly like what you're looking for, there's more than enough to get you started in the right direction.